# Wordpress Password Manipulation using Java or Sql How?

Tags: java, mysql, wordpress, password-encryption, authentication

I have a web application written in Java using mysql.
Also a wordpress installation on the same machine.
I would like to use the wordpress wp_users table as the users table for my application too.
But to do that, I need to be able to decript the password.

How does one do that in java?

Comment: You usually don't decrypt the passwords as much as you hash the passwords and compare the hashes.  You will need to figure out what kind of password hash WP uses and use the same one in Java.  I believe it's using phpass.  Here is a site that may give more info on how the hash works:  http://www.openwall.com/phpass/

Comment: WP passwords are not encrypted. They are hashed. You can see the code in `PasswordHash::HashPassword()` and replicate that in Java.

Comment: I found something on github: https://github.com/Mollom/phpass-java  This would allow me to authenticate but not retrieve a password, right?